# "Could not find gem …" error with bundler using custom gem source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

In my Gemfile I require a gem from a custom source with this line:

```
gem 'very-secret-gem', source:'https://foo.example.com/'
```

`bundle install` completes fine:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index from https://foo.example.com/
Fetching source index from https://foo.example.com/
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
…
Resolving dependencies...
…
Installing very-secret-gem 1.5.1
…
Bundle complete! 47 Gemfile dependencies, 116 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But running commands that use ruby fail (empty Rakefile here):

```
$ bundle exec rake -T
Could not find gem 'very-secret-gem (>= 0) ruby' in rubygems repository https://foo.example.com/.
Source does not contain any versions of 'very-secret-gem (>= 0) ruby'
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Running `bundle install` at this point as advised in the error message will not help.

**Why is it, and how to fix it?**

If I specify the gem in a source block, it fails just the same:

```
source 'https://foo.example.com/' do
  gem 'very-secret-gem'
end
```

More interestingly, if I specify the sources at the beginning of the file, not tied to any gems, it works fine:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://foo.example.com/'
gem 'very-secret-gem'
```

…but bundler advises against it:

```
Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source`
more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in
installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to
indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade
this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.
```

#### Versions:

```
$ ruby -v    # => ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
$ gem -v     # => 2.4.5
$ bundle -v  # => Bundler version 1.8.2
```

#### Update

Seems like a bundler bug. The presence of another `gem` with `:path` seems to be what triggers it. A test app is here: https://github.com/kch/bundler-source-bug

GH issue for bundler here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3417

Comment: further investigation leads me to suspect a bug in bundler involving another requiring gem using `:path`

Comment: Hello, did you fill a bug to Bundler? If so, could you please provide a link to the relative issue, so that I can follow the updatings? I opened an [issue about this on Rails assets](https://github.com/rails-assets/rails-assets/issues/226) and I would like to link to the related Bundler issue, if any

Comment: did now https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3417

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in Bundler 1.8.3 (released today).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend upgrading to atleast **bundler 1.8.5** per [this issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3430), which not only has problem with multiple sources but custom paths as well - this way you are not locked into specific gemfile syntax to work around bugs with bundler, custom sources, and bundle exec.

I spent all morning fighting dependency issues and dancing around syntax,

```
gem update bundler
```

was all I needed, all my problems disappeared.

keep an eye on the [changelog](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.8.5/CHANGELOG.md), there appears to be quite a few minor patches as of late.